# MySQL - Subtract one from value every minute

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to set up MySQL so that it can subtract one from all values in a row every minute. Once that value equals 0, I would like MySQL to delete that row, and execute a query which adds a row to another table. Before I ask how this can be done, I first would like to know if such a thing is even possible. I have looked around on Google using the search term "automatic run sql query", and unless I am incorrectly understanding what I have read, it is possible, but how can I do something like what I want? What I want would need an if statement to work, but does MySQL even have such a thing as if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the recurrent option in the MySQL event scheduler. You an set it to run every min and then have your logic in it.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html

Comment: Okay, thanks! I think that if I took some time to piece the queries together, I could use your link to help me do the rest. I can't upvote your answer (not enough rep), but will accept in 10 minutes. **Edit: I just reached the rep limit. It looks like you'll be getting that upvote after all.**

Answer (score 0):

Using recurrent event will help you to accomplish this. Create an event to execute every minute.

```
CREATE EVENT subtractRow 
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS NOW
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
COMMENT 'Row Subtraction'
DO
-- WRITE QUERY TO SUBTRACT ROW VALUE HERE
```